# Use newer version of Android Gradle Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android

I just upgraded to android studio 1.0 and and getting this error to use new Android Gradle here:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

I have already change this in gradle-wrapper to the correct url

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

And set this in app.gradle

```
minifyEnabled false
```

What do I need to change this to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

as Gradle for Android 1.0 is now available.